# I want to alternate, repeat, click, or check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using unfamiliar English sentences, so I'm sorry if something goes wrong.

Checkboxes (etc.), depending on the keydown operation,
instead
repeat,
I want to click or confirm.

For example, on the same page
`span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton`
There are multiple things like the same checkbox in the element.

```
$('Span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton')[2]

$('Span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton')[3]

$('Span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton')[4]
```

And suppose each has an element that you can specify.

---

```
$ (Window).keydown(function (e) {

  if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 67) {

    $('Span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton')[2].checked;

    $('Span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton')[3].checked;

    $('Span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton')[4].checked;

    $('Span.ClapLv1FormRadioButton')[2].checked;

    repetition.check;

  });

});
```

---

I want to make it work as above.
If you press the same key code in succession, you want to check it by repeating it alternately.

I also referred to the following site, but I can't implement the behavior I expected.

https://www.clarenet.co.jp/column/coding/jquery%E3%81%A7%E3%80%81%E9%A0%86%E7%95%AA%E3%81%AB%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B-when-done/

How do I implement the functionality I need?

Please teach me.

Operating environment Windows 10 Chrome 64bit https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-and-javascript-inject/ckddknfdmcemedlmmebildepcmneakaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understang that English is not your language... And thanks for the effort.

> If you press the same key code in succession, you want to check it by repeating it alternately.

I think you want something like this *(while really unsure!!)*

```js
var activeRadio = 0;
$(window).on("keydown", function (e) {

  if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 67) { // ALT+SHIF+c
    $('.ClapLv1FormRadioButton').eq(activeRadio).prop("checked", true);
  }

  activeRadio = (activeRadio+1 > $(".ClapLv1FormRadioButton").length-1) ? 0 : activeRadio+1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Hit [ALT]+[CTRL]+[C] to cycle the radio inputs...<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" class="ClapLv1FormRadioButton" name="somename">1<br>
<input type="radio" class="ClapLv1FormRadioButton" name="somename">2<br>
<input type="radio" class="ClapLv1FormRadioButton" name="somename">3<br>
<input type="radio" class="ClapLv1FormRadioButton" name="somename">4<br>
<input type="radio" class="ClapLv1FormRadioButton" name="somename">5<br>
<input type="radio" class="ClapLv1FormRadioButton" name="somename">6<br>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Can you see the source of the page by pasting it in the address bar?

view-source: https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/question/post/form

I am trying to implement arbitrary processing on another person's site.

Comment: The actual page is here, but https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/question/post/form
Since membership registration is required, it is difficult to accurately convey the situation to non-Japanese people.

Comment: The source of the page is like this.　
view-source:chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/question/post/form

Comment: No I can't reach it. It is a login page.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I was able to confirm the operation.

However,
The page I was trying was a page with a closed parent element or couldn't be scraped, so I gave up and ran it on another page and it succeeded.